# MacBook is getting slow than before suddenly

Tags: usb, filesystems, macbook, macos-sierra

My Macbook is getting slow than before. I'm not sure exactly since It's happened. But After I installed MS office the application was very slow when to type and operate the function. Then I recognized the issue. I was thinking Mac is slow even though I have enough memory and good performance CPU.

It's frequently happened to disturb my key stroke such typing characters on Web form or MS office documents. It's not fixed the frequencies but It's happended within every 2 mins at least. Moreover, When USB memory is connected it's more slower than without dongle. Even I'm not accessing a file on USB memory from Applications such MS Excel file and also I excluded to scan USB memory on Norton.

I can see the USB memory has indicator is blinking about 40 mins after I reconnected. But I can not find a process is accessing the memory dongle. I used the command to check which process is accessing memory dongle. But I could not find a process.

lsof | grep /Volumes/Lexar

I tried to uninstall Norton and reinstall MS Office. But no luck.

I'm thinking the problem is unknown virus, USB port of macBook, Memory, BUS on motherboard, Lexar USB memory, input method program of Sierra, file system, spotlite indexing or attack form network.

Environment:
Macbook Mid 2016/DualCore/HTT/2.5Ghz/8GB/500GB(Free 150GB)/Sierra latest

Do you know how to check/fix the issue?

Comment: I recommend you show us your activity monitor screen to show the list of all the processes running it can either not enough ram or your cpu cycle is interrupted we need a little bit more information (start with the basics and we will work our way up)

Comment: @Hamuel, Thank you very for the word. I will monitor the process and report again when it's happened.